# Matches without matching alternations

Tags: regex, perl

I want to filter some substrings from a string:

```
.
.
th>Di, -12 ;0907<th
th>Mi, -44 ;1007<th
th>Do, -66 ;1107<th
.
.
```

My perl script is:

```
.
.
my (@d,$h,$s);
@d=$h=~/(th>(Di|Mi|Do), -\d\d ;\d\d\d\d<th)/igs;
foreach $s (@d)
   {print  "$s\n";};  

Output is:
th>Di, -12 ;0907<th
Di
th>Mi, -44 ;1007<th
Mi
th>Do, -66 ;1107<th
Do
```

My problem, I need this output:

```
th>Di, -12 ;0907<th
th>Mi, -44 ;1007<th
th>Do, -66 ;1107<th
```

How can I filter matches without alternations within the regex?

Comment: Please explain. Your "Output is" looks equal to "I need this output"... if its just about the "Di, Mi, Do" on a separate line, exclude that from being a matchgroup using the `?:` operator: `/(th>(?:Di|Mi|Do), -\d\d ;\d\d\d\d<th)/igs`

Comment: Your code is incorrect. The variable `$h` is undefined when used in the regular expression. I know what it contains but could be confused for anyone who copy&paste your code trying to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Next time I will be more precisely.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the easiest way would be just to turn a capturing group into a non-capturing one with `?:` regex operator:

```
@d=$h=~/(th>(?:Di|Mi|Do), -\d\d ;\d\d\d\d<th)/igs;
```

Actually, `?:` often is used with `|`: to limit the alternation's scope, you have to use parenthesis, but you don't have to leverage their main effect (capturing) too.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your data has the same amount of numbers in the following lines, you could do..

```
(th>(?:Di|Mi|Do),\s+-\d{2}\s+;\d{4}<th)
```

If the length of your numbers vary, then I would do.

```
(th>(?:Di|Mi|Do),\s+-\d+\s+;\d+<th)
```

Instead of using a space in your regex, use `\s`:

```
\s+          matches whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
```

Reason being, if your data has more than one space, then regular expression will not match the following:

```
th>Di,  -12  ;0907<th
th>Mi,   -44  ;1007<th
```

Comment: Thank you - also for your additional hint.